# "instance of" equivalent in Schematron/XPath

Tags: xpath, schematron

I have found that Saxon implementation of XPath 2.0 supports both 'instance of' and 'castable as' as valid ways of obtaining the type of a value, [as explained in this website](http://xfront.com/awesome-power-of-schematron-plus-xpath2/index.html).
This seems to be a Saxon specific syntax. Does a standard way of obtaining the type of a node exist?

Comment: XPath 2.0 is a W3C recommendation that Saxon implements and the operators `instance of` and `castable as` are part of that standard, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-instance-of and https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-castable. I am not sure what you have in mind when asking about a "standard way", are you talking about XPath 1.0?

Comment: Yeah, wasn't able to find the official documentation and only Saxon results appeared (so I assumed it was a Saxon thing). This is the answer I was looking for, so if you reply it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath 2.0 is a W3C recommendation that Saxon implements and the operators `instance of` and `castable as` a part of that standard, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-instance-of and https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-castable.